# Правильное написание предложения со знаками препинапия.

Tags: пунктуация

Фэнтези самый лучший жанр искусства.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Фэнтези - самый лучший жанр искусства.

Подлежащее и именная часть сказуемого выражена сущ. в И.п. Тире разделяет подлежащее и группу сказуемого, в устной речи делается пауза.

Comment: Материал 5-го класса...